# Cant open device on raspberry pi 3b+ with hidapi hidtest

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, hid, hidapi

> pi@led-panel:~/hidapi/hidtest $ sudo ./test  hidapi test/example tool.
> Compiled with hidapi version 0.13.0, runtime version 0.13.0.
> Compile-time version matches runtime version of hidapi. Device Found
> type: 17ef 6019   path: 1-1.1.3:1.0   serial_number: (null)
> Manufacturer: Logitech   Product:      Lenovo USB Optical Mouse
> Release:      7200   Interface:    0   Usage (page): 0x0 (0x0)   Bus
> type: 1 unable to open device pi@led-panel:~/hidapi/hidtest $

i have only a usb mouse connected on 64 bit raspbian
please help

Comment: Is your mouse in use by the display manager? Why is it a problem that hidtest can't open it?

Comment: i removed the xserver lightdm and all desktop apps and it still shows the same error

Comment: i ran the commands with sudo and it spid out a differend error